# How to upgrade Firebase through "Pod Install" in Swift 4.0, Xcode

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

I realized I need to update Firebase version to latest 4.x from 3.11.
I updated the pod file by adding " pod 'Firebase','~> 4.00'"
But it is not working.

```
      # Pods for Firebase
      pod 'Firebase','~> 4.00'
```

How can I upgrade it? Also is there any migration tool for Firebase 4 in Swift? Many thanks!

Comment: install like this with only  pod 'Firebase'. you can update your firebase

Comment: Don't forget to run `pod update` after changing the Podfile.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it by running `pod update` in terminal.

**If your Pod update fails**

1. Install cococoapods deintegrate and clean by running the following `$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate` and `$ sudo gem install cocoapods-clean`
2. Run `pod deintegrate`
3. Run `pod clean`
4. And then check your `podfile` has the latest Firebase pod and run `pod install`

This method will remove **all** of your pods, clean them and reinstall them after running `pod install`.

Answer (score 1):

**Check this one, its working fine**

In your pod, remove a pod version from it.

Link: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Firebase

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

run `pod update` in your terminal

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have all of the latest pods.
run

```
pod repo update
```

then

```
pod update Firebase
```